# Handling authentication redirects with wget

Tags: linux, wget

Trying to download this file with wget from linux shell, but looks like it cannot handle the authentication redirect, even though I specified --max-redirect=10 parameter. Instead it ends up downloading HTML response from live.com instead of final txt file.

```
wget --max-redirect=10 -O default.style.txt https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=C45DFAE025D1C49D%21114939&authkey=%21ADYkB0FOydhlb7I&ithint=file%2ctxt
```

Any ideas on how to get this command to work? Thanks!

Comment: Just a plain ol' `wget --no-check-certificate "https://onedrive.live.com/download?resid=C45DFAE025D1C49D%21114939&authkey=%21ADYkB0FOydhlb7I&ithint=file%2ctxt"` worked fine for me. I got the "default osm2pgsql .style file". Although the name `default.style.txt?download&psid=1` leaves a bit to be desired.

Comment: Oh! Perhaps it's the double quotes that are lacking around your URL. Missing that will cause your shell to go batty as it parses that thing.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of JNevill's comment, missing double quotes around url was the caveat